# For each $\beta \in(0,1)$, give a sequence $\{a_j\}\subset(0,1)$ with $\prod (1-\alpha_j) = \beta $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

> Suppose $\{\alpha_j\} \subset (0,1)$. Give a sequence ${\alpha_j}$ such that $\prod (1-\alpha_j) = \beta $, where $\beta \in (0,1)$

I was able to prove part a. That is the infinite product of $(1-a_j)$ is positive iff $\sum \alpha_j < \infty $.

However, I have no idea how to exhibit a sequence ${a_j}$ so that the infinite product of $1-\alpha_j$ is some $\beta$ that is in $(0,1)$. Would I need to construct a specific sequence or a more general case?

Any help would be much appreciated as I am really stuck and don't have much of an idea even where to begin.

Comment: *Hint.* Pick a sequence $\{\beta_n\}_{n\geq1}\subset(0,1)$ together with $\beta_0 =1$which monotonely decreases to $\beta$ and define $\{a_n\}$ to satisfy $1-a_n = \beta_n/\beta_{n-1}$.

Comment: The question has  nothing to do with measure theory.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This question is from Folland's Real Analysis, which is a primarily a text on measure theory, but perhaps this has something to do with the cantor set? I'm not too sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha_j=1-\exp(-t\,/\,2^{\,j})$ where $t =-\log \, \beta$. Can you verify that this sequence has the desired properties?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I would show that the infinite product of such a sequence is B, where B is between 0 and 1. I've never shown that an infinite product of anything is equal to a particular value before. How should I proceed in doing this? thanks.

Comment: $\prod_{j=1}^{N} e^{-\frac t {2^{j}}} =e^{-\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac t {2^{j}}}$. Let $N \to \infty$ and use the  fact that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac t {2^{j}}=t$.

Comment: thanks makes perfect sense.

Comment: That is, $$\alpha_j=1-\beta^{2^{-j}}$$